# Need Freemarker method/function to detect US holiday name from a given date

Tags: freemarker

Does anyone know of a Freemarker function/method that returns the name of a US holiday for a given date?

I've written a function to retrieve the previous business day (Mon-Fri) for any given date, but if the previous business day happens to be one of ten recognized holidays at our company, then I need to step back one day from that to then run my getPreviousBusinessDay function.

Here is my getPreviousBusinessDay function:

```
<#function getPreviousBusinessDay date>
  <#local dateAsEpochMS = date?long>  <#-- Convert date to epoch time in milliseconds -->
  <#local outie = ""/>
  <#local dayOfWeek = date?string("EEEE")>
  <#if dayOfWeek = "Monday">
    <#local outie = dateAsEpochMS - 259200000> <#-- subtract 3 days in milliseconds -->
  <#elseif dayOfWeek = "Sunday">
    <#local outie = dateAsEpochMS - 172800000> <#-- subtract 2 days in milliseconds -->  
  <#else>
    <#local outie = dateAsEpochMS - 86400000> <#-- subtract 1 days in milliseconds -->
  </#if>
  <#local outie = outie?number_to_date?string("MMMM d, YYYY")>
  <#return outie>
</#function>
```

So if you enter "August 1, 2022" (a Monday) into the function:

```
${getPreviousBusinessDay("August 1, 2022"?date)}
```

it returns the previous Friday date:

```
July 29, 2022
```

That's all well and good, but hence my problem if the previous business day happens to be one of those ten holidays that we're closed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `<#function isBusinessDay(date)>`, that returns `true` for days that aren't weekend days, and not in the set of knows corporate holidays. Then in `getPreviousBusinessDay` you just step back one day in a loop until `isBusinessDay(date)` returns `true`.

But, where/how is the information about the corporate holydays stored? Also it will be different each year, so it's something that will have to be updated time to time.

BTW, doing logic like this in templates is bad practice. I would create some service in Java that can answer all these questions, and just call that.

Also be careful with substracting one day in millies. That can break if you are using a time zone that day light saving, and you date-time is near midnight.